# WPF event handler in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2008

When i went to add an event to the button which i dragged and dropped from toolbox to the window, the event handler on the properties window was not visible..  because of this reason, i added the event manually (by typing). but after when i built it and pressed F5, the button was not firing the event.

Comment: You have to the event in XAML and C#.

Answer (score 0):

here is a little example that must be work ;-)

```
<Window x:Class="WpfStackOverflowSpielWiese.Window8"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Window8"
        Height="300"
        Width="300">
  <Grid>
    <Button Click="Button_Click" />
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

code behind

```
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfStackOverflowSpielWiese
{
  /// <summary>
  /// Interaction logic for Window8.xaml
  /// </summary>
  public partial class Window8 : Window
  {
    public Window8() {
      InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
      // do something....
    }
  }
}
```

hope that helps you...

Comment: I solved it myself :-) ...What i did was i updated my visual studio 2008 to SP1. Now event handler is there at the properties window..everything is working fine..Thank you all came to help me. cheers!!!!